# How to scroll to top in IOS7 UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

In IOS6 I have the following code to scroll to the top of a UITableView

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

In IOS7 this doesn't work anymore. The table view isn't scrolled completely to the top (but almost).

Comment: Is it possible that what you're missing is 20 px from the new status bar style? This happened to me in a bunch of places - there is a bug fix in IB that makes a correct adjustment for the status bar. This can result in either 20 px on the bottom or on the top missing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By the help from some other answers here I managed to get it working. To avoid a crash I must first check that there are some sections. NsNotFound can be used as a row index if the first section has no rows. Hopefully this should be a generic function to be placed in a UITableViewController:

```
-(void) scrollToTop
{
    if ([self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView] > 0)
    {
        NSIndexPath* top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:top atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost to similar to the answer that I posted. So you should have accepted that answer. Anyway, if your problem is solved, accept an answer so that it can be helpful to others.

Comment: Although you can target the first row with this, you won't necessarily reveal any table header view that's above even the first row. Semantically, you just want to set a contentOffset on the table view that takes into account the contentInset that it has been given (see the code in my answer below).

Comment: Indeed, the situation couldn't be simpler.  Use idStar's code which is, simply, the correct code to zero a table!

Answer (score 127):

In iOS7, whole screen UITableView and UIScrollView components, by default, adjust content and scroll indicator insets to just make everything work. However, as you've noticed CGPointZero no longer represents the content offset that takes you to the visual "top".

Use this instead:

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
```

Here, you don't have to worry about if you have sections or rows. You also don't tell the Table View to target the first row, and then wonder why it didn't show all of your very tall table header view, etc.

Comment: I like your method. Even better if you use [UITableView setContentOffset:animated:], because you can then animate to that position.

Comment: @siburb Agreed, using that method to animate it is often an even better way to use that calculation, in many contexts.

Comment: @siburb Funny, it works for me with self.tableView.contentOffset but it doesn't work with [UITableView setContentOffset:animated:]?!

Comment: Sorry, looking back on my comment, it is not clear what I meant. "setContentOffset" is an instance method, not a class method, so you use it like this:
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];

Comment: This is a great place for C99 syntax: `(CGPoint){.y = -self.tableView.contentInset.top}`. (x will be initialized to 0.)

Comment: unavailable in swift

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: @MorbZ: Just use an `if` condition to check if the table has any rows.

Comment: it's better to do it with the correct code, which is given in idStar's answer.  Note that if it has no rows now, it may later have rows and then it will be in the wrong place (particularly if you're trying to get it to "start right")

Answer (score 21):

Based on the accepted answer from @Markus Johansson, here is the Swift code version:

```
func scrollToTop() {
    if (self.tableView.numberOfSections > 0 ) {
        let top = NSIndexPath(row: Foundation.NSNotFound, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: top as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me but (self.numberOfSectionsInTableView(self.tableView) got an error message, I substituted it with tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) and then it worked

Answer (score 4):

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.sampleTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath,
atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

or

```
self.sampleTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated:false)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
float systemVersion= [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if(systemVersion >= 7.0f)
{
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;   
}
```

Try this code in `viewDidLoad()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Here is idStar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20011690/5666995) in updated Swift 3 syntax:

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
```

With animation:

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3

If you have table view headers CGPointZero may not work for you, but this always does the trick to scroll to top.

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can still use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` for the purpose

Answer (score 2):

I realize this has been answered but I just wanted to give another option:

```
CGRect frame = {{0, 0},{1, 1}};
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

This always guarantees the UITableView will scroll to the top. The accepted answer:

```
NSIndexPath* top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:top atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

was not working for me because I was scrolling to a tableHeaderView and not a cell.

Using `scrollRectToVisible` works on iOS 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 UITableViewExtension:

```
func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
    if numberOfSections > 0 {
        let topIndexPath = IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: 0)
        scrollToRow(at: topIndexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift I used:

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
```

but @Alvin George's works great