# Scroll to Table View Header top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` header that takes up the full frame of the screen.

Every time the app goes in the background, and then comes back into the foreground/active, I would like the **screen to be set back to the header top**.

I've only seen answers having to do with scrolling to the top of the table with something like these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243177/how-to-scroll-to-top-in-ios7-uitableview) that use something like `self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: top, at: .top, animated: true)`, but that doesn't work because it only scrolls back to Section 0 Row 0 of the `UITableView` not the top of the header of the `UITableView`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Tried this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.setContentOffset( CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) , animated: true)
}
```

And here is some noteworthy table setup code:

```
// Set up Frames
let headerFrame: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
// Background Table
self.tableView.isPagingEnabled = true

// Set up Table Header
let header = UIView(frame: headerFrame)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

Comment: can you post your storyboard screenshot

Comment: @Joe the storyboard is pretty blank because I'm doing most of this in code, is there any specific code I can add to help?

Comment: can you update your code and screenshot of your problem. thats helps everyone...

Comment: did you set frame for ur header... I need to see your header code...

Comment: try this  tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect.zero and make sure you have define header size.

Comment: how big is your tableView..r u loading more data into it.if yes...then its a wrong idea...note..your problem is fixable if you ready to post your code

Comment: @Joe I added some noteworthy table/header code, does that help?

Comment: change your header frame to CGRect.zero

Comment: to define header height func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60.0    
}

Comment: Oh perfect that makes sense too!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126467/discussion-between-joe-and-srmr).

Comment: @Joe got it solved by the answer below but thanks for the other option!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TableView is a scroll view subclass, so I imagine this should work:

```
 self.tableView.setContentOffset( CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) , animated: true)
```

ViewWillAppear does not get called when app enters foreground. Register you VC for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`

Comment: I've confirmed that this works. Just add this to your `viewWillAppear`

Comment: For some reason I tried it and it didn't work for me.  I posted my code above so you could see if I was doing something different than recommended.  But to test it I ran the app, scrolled down to the second section of the tableview, pushed home to send the app into the background, then tapped the app icon to bring the app back into the foreground, but it stayed at the second section of the tableview instead of scrolling to the top/header.

Comment: @SRMR did the view will appear method get called?

Comment: @IlyaLapan No I put a breakpoint on it, and it only got called when the app initially loaded, but not when it came back from background

Comment: That is because view will appear does not get called when you app enters foreground.

Comment: YES! That worked so perfectly.  Just added a selector method via the road you described.  Thank you so much!

Comment: When the app gets put into "Multitasking mode" (Home button hit twice) or just hitting home button once and then tapping the app icon, sometimes this method isn't getting called, do you know why that would be?

Answer (score 8):

You can scroll to Section Header, try following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: yourSectionIndex)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

For Row add: **NSNotFound**

Change .top/.bottom in "scrollToRow" as per your requirement.